# How do I track (Google Analytics) individual file downloads when I use the <asp:hyperlink> tag?

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics

I am familiar with tracking file downloads using this method:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/files/map.pdf" onClick="javascript: pageTracker._trackPageview('/downloads/map'); ">
```

But now I need to track a file download using this code:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" runat="server" 
    NavigateUrl="~/Protected/Download.aspx?pfile=logos.zip" 
    ForeColor="Black" style="text-decoration:none"><b>Download<img src="../external_files/images/downloadzip.gif" 
    style="width: 40px; height: 40px" border="0" /></b>
</asp:HyperLink>
```

From what I found using the
`onClick="javascript: pageTracker._trackPageview('/downloads/map');`
will not work. I also read that `onClick` doesn't even work with asp:hyperlink.

**I do not know ASP, what is the easiest way for me to track the download of this file? I have tried using a asp:linkbutton, but I haven't had success(I could be coding it wrong though).**

**EDIT:**
Another way of explaining my problem is:
I came across this asp link that I need to track the file download, but I don't know asp or how to edit/rewrite the statement to do so.

Comment: did not marker answer?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of asp:hyperlink, you might consider using another asp control that supports the `OnClientClick` attribute.

Another choice would be to use JavaScript (use your favorite library, i.e., jQuery) to attach the Google Analytics Event Tracking code to your asp:hyperlink:

```
jQuery("#GeneratedIDForHyperLink3").click(
    function() { 
        try { 
            pageTracker._trackEvent(categoryVal, actionVal, labelVal);
        } catch(err) {}
    });
```

You could do something like this in a document.ready() block.

**UPDATE**

You can use a asp:linkbutton, adding javascript to the OnClientClick to prevent posting the buttons click action to the server.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="HyperLink3" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" Style="text-decoration: none" OnClientClick="javascript: pageTracker._trackPageview('/downloads/map');document.location = '/Protected/Download.aspx?pfile=logos.zip';return false;">
<b>Download<img alt="" src="../external_files/images/downloadzip.gif" style="width: 40px; height: 40px" border="0" /></b>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Notice that OnClientClick calls your Google track event function, then changes the document location, and as a safety, returns false to prevent posting to the server.

I wouldnt call this a best practice and would personally consider doing it a different way.

Comment: jQuery is a little above me as well. How could I rewrite the asp:hyperlink with the OnClientClick and the GA code?

Comment: Is there are reason you must use the asp:hyperlink? Is there are reason you can't just do the straight HTML that you are comfortable with? The asp:hyperlink doesn't directly support the OnClientClick, but the asp:imagebutton and asp:linkbutton do. Those will unfortunately render as html controls(buttons) that will ultimately post to the server. you can mitigate that with javascript. I will edit my response and add a sample.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using OnClientClick?  OnClick executes server side where as OnClientClick works on client side before control is passed to the server.

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        function Foo() {
            javascript: window.open("~/Protected/Download.aspx?pfile=logos.zip");
        }
        $("#MyLinkButton").click(function () {
            javascript: pageTracker._trackPageview('/downloads/map');
        });
    });
</script>

<asp:LinkButton ID="MyLinkButton" runat="server" 
                Text="ClickMe" OnClientClick="Foo()" />
```

Or if you wanted to handle the page tracking on the server side, you could try something like-a-so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        function Foo() {
            javascript: window.open("~/Protected/Download.aspx?pfile=logos.zip");
        }
    });
</script>

<asp:LinkButton ID="MyLinkButton" runat="server" 
                Text="ClickMe" OnClientClick="Foo()" OnClick="MyLinkButton_Click" />

// Server side code
public void MyLinkButton_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pageTracker._trackPageview('/downloads/map');
}
```

When I originally asked what your asp:LinkButton code looked like, I was sure it looked similar to your asp:HyperLink code that you posted but asp:LinkButton doesn't have an attribute for 'NavigateUrl'. Let me know if this is more along the lines of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can always override the OnLoad() method and set the onClick attribute that way. For example:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
     base.OnLoad(e)
     this.Attributes["onClick"] = "javascript: pageTracker._trackPageview('/downloads/map'); ";
}
```